# google_fonts is not working in flutter after app build

Tags: flutter, google-fonts

when I am in debug mode, it's just working fine, but after app build, Google fonts is not working on the mobile, the app is using the regular font.

I checked and did all available steps to solve the issue,yet I failed!

Steps I did:

1. In my pubspec.yaml file, I added dependencies as instruction  and added `import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';`  in every file.Then I ran the  "$flutter pub get" Command,then I restarted the IDE, when it returned the same result, then I did the whole procedure with the PC restart, but nothing changed.
2. I checked the android manifest file, and the line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` is already there.
3. Switched the IDE VS code to android studio, still not working.
4. I deleted every related file from mobile, and restarted the mobile, i did a "Clean installation(?!)" with internet connection, but no joy!

Is there any way to solve the issue?

Comment: can you share your code you used google fonts

Comment: @Timurturbil [here the link of my code] (https://controlc.com/3e5a1acce)

Comment: I used your code and it works well. I run it with debug and there was no error. what do you mean by after app build ?  your fonts also work well

Comment: @Timurturbil I am talking about apk, after running the command $flutter build apk , flutter produce an apk file , when I install the apk in my mobile, the problem arise, in debug mode, it is working fine in my side too!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem. I added:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET/>`

to the `app_directory/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`, and to `app_directory/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` as well.

The end result looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    //...
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to download the font files from fonts.google.com and place them in a directory in top level directory of your application.
Also configure them jn pubspec.yaml as assets.

Follow the steps mentions here
https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts

Comment: mentioned the way how to do it in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71275718/17411652